# validar usuario php sqlserver

Tags: php, sql-server

Hola a todos que me leen, quisiera un apoyo de la comunidad ya que recien estoy empezando en el mundo de la programación. Estoy intentando crear un apirest para validar login con usuario y contraseña usando php con sqlserver. La conexion es exitosa, el error se presenta desde la linea 10 del archivo validar_usuario2.php. Espero su ayuda, muchas gracias!.

Este es el contenido de mi tabla:

```
create table usuario (
usu_usuario varchar (50),
usu_password    varchar (12),
usu_nombres varchar (50),
usu_apellidos   varchar (50)
)
go
```

Esto el archivo conexion.php:

```
<?php
$serverName = "SQL5050.site4now.net";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"DB_A511C0_bdpruebahost", "UID"=>"DB_A511C0_bdpruebahost_admin", "PWD"=>"*****");
$conn =  sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
    echo "Conexion exitosa.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Conexion no se pudo establecer.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Este es el archivo validar_usuario2.php

```
<?php

require_once 'conexion.php';

$usu_usuario= $_REQUEST['usu_usuario'];
$usu_password= $_REQUEST['usu_password'];

$sentencia=sqlsrv_prepare($conn,"SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE usu_usuario=? AND usu_password=?");

mssql_bind ('ss',$sentencia,$usu_usuario,$usu_password);

$sentencia->mssql_execute();

$resultado = $sentencia->get_result();
if ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo json_encode($fila,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);     
}
$sentencia->close();
$conn->close();
?>
´´´
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el error que se genera?

Answer (score 0):

Esa sentencia en Sql Server no es correcta, o al menos no te devolverá los resultados deseados, ya que usuario = a lo que le llega como parámetro siempre que la columna sea de un tipo char/varchar/nvachar o similar, no funcionará. Prueba a encerrar el contenido de lo que envías entre apóstrofes:

```
$sentencia=sqlsrv_prepare($conn,"SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE usu_usuario='?' AND usu_password='?'");
```